# spring boot pageable configure params name

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring Boot v1.5.2.RELEASE.

My controller is like this:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/list_praxis")
public
@ResponseBody
ModelAndView login(Pageable pageable,HttpServletRequest request) {
    return new ModelAndView(new WebJsonView());
}
```

My parameters `size:10 page:0`, Pageable works fine.

But now I want to change my parameters to  `pageSize:10 currentPage:0`.

Pageable doesn't work, because pageable can only receive `size` and `page`, and doesn't support other parameter names.

How can I configure this to use `pageSize` and `currentPage` instead of `size` and `page`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would work for you.

```html
@Configuration
public class RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration extends SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration{

    @Override
    protected void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
           config.setPageParamName("p")
                 .setLimitParamName("l")
                 .setSortParamName("s");
    }
}
```

This configuration would set the paging parameter to p, the size parameter to l, and the sort parameter to s:

Comment: I am running a Springboot 1.5.5 currently and this won't work :-(

Comment: @DirkSchumacher You could try application properties as shown in the [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html), or check the answer below.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use spring's application properties like this

```
spring.data.web.pageable.page-parameter: pageNumber
spring.data.web.pageable.size-parameter: pageSize
```

You can learn about other common application properties [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html).